# Overflow method not working in html page.

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment for school which is designing an app with HTML. I am having trouble with the contents of the apps bleeding over at the bottom when you scroll down. I tried various options of the overflow method and nothing seems to work. I included the entire css and html. Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help me out!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <link href=https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="table-wrapper">
      <div id="table-scroll">
    <section class="container">
      <nav>
        <img src="images/status bar.png" width="360" height="24" alt=""/>
        <div class="app-bar">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ham-menu"><img src="images/menu.png" width="24" height="24" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="title">Washington at State Station</td>
      <td class="search-icon"><img src="images/search.png" width="24" height="24" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="icon"><img src="images/menu-item.png" width="5" height="24" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
   </div>
      <div class="route-bar"><table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h2>Line</h2></td>
      <td class="dest"><h2>Destination</h2></td>
      <td class="times"><h2>Arrival</h2></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
      </nav>
      <section class="bus-list">
            <div class="info">
             <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>124</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Eastbound</h1>
        <h3>Navy Pier</h3></td>
      <td class="times"><h1>5 Min</h1>
        <h3>Freq. 10 min</h3>
          </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
          </div>
       <div class="info">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h1>124</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Southbound</h1>        <h3>Navy Pier</h3></td>
      <td class="times"><h1>10 Min</h1>
         <h3>Freq. 10 min</h3>
          </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
          </div>
      <div class="info">
       <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h1>J14</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Southbound</h1>
        <h3>103rd/Stony Island</h3></td>
      <td class="times"><h1>15 Min</h1>
        <h3>Freq. 15 min</h3></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
          <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>151</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Northbound</h1>
        <h3>Devon/Clark</h3></td>
      <td class="times"><h1>16 Min</h1>
        <h3>Freq. 16 min</h3></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
          </div>
         <div class="info">
          <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>60</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Eastbound</h1>
        <h3>Randolph/Harbor Dr</h3></td>
      <td class="times"><h1>18 Min</h1>
        <h3>Freq. 20 min</h3></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
       <div class="info">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>6X</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Reroute</h1>
        <h3>Jackson Park Express</h3>
        </td>
      <td class="times"><h1>30 Min</h1>
        <h3>Freq. N/A</h3></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
          </div>

          <div class="info">
       <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>4</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Out of Service</h1>
        <h3>Cottage Grove</h3>
        <h3>Resumes 12:10 am</h3></td>
      <td class="alert">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
     </div>
           <div class="info">
       <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>20</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Out of Service</h1>
        <h3>Madison</h3>
        <h3>Resumes 12:10 am</h3></td>
</td>
      <td class="alert">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
     </div>
       <div class="info">
       <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="lines"><h1>157</h1></td>
      <td class="dest"><h1>Out of Service</h1>
        <h3>Streeterville/Taylor</h3>
        <h3>Resumes 6:00 am</h3></td>
              <td class="alert">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
     </div>
      </section>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>


CSS

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  background-color: #6E6C6C;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

#table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#table-scroll {
   height: 647px;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:600;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color:#02356A;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color:#02356A;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 360px;
  height: 667px;
}

nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 360px;
  height: 111px;
  background-color: #164F9C;
}

.bus-list {
  padding-top: 158px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.info {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e5edf2;
  border-bottom: thin #000000 solid;
}

.info:hover {
    background-color: #81aef1;
}

.content {
    width: 90%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.icon {
    width: 4px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    }

.title {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 180px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

.ham-menu {
    width: 24px;
}

.search-icon {
    padding-left: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}

.app-bar {
    padding: 16px;
}

.route-bar {
    background-color:#02356A;
    height: 48px;
    width: 360px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
}

.lines {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.dest {
    width: 37%;
}

.times {
    width: 27%;
    text-align: right;
}

.bottom-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 425px;
}

.alert {
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/Steve/bloc/frontend/images/alerts.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 42px 38px;
    background-position: right;
    width: 27%;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 360px;
    bottom: 37px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image:url(file:///C:/Users/Steve/bloc/frontend/images/bottom-bar.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `bottom: 37px;` in your CSS in the footer. Set this to 0px and you won't see the element under it anymore.

Comment: That worked! I was playing around with the measurements but never thought of setting it to 0. Thanks again!

Comment: you could mark my answer as correct then. Glad I could help.